# How do i fix Sqlexception was unhandled

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms-designer

I keep getting an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Code:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO UserRegister(LastName, FirstName, M.I, Username, Password, Email, Address, ContactNumber, Gender, BloodType)  
                      VALUES (@txtLName, @txtFName, @txtMI, @txtRegUsername, @txtRegPassword, @txtEmail, @txtHomeAddress, @txtContactno, @cmbGender, @cmbBloodtype)", sql);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@M.I", txtMI.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtRegusername.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtRegpassword.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtHomeaddress.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", txtContactno.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", cmbGender.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BloodType", cmbBloodtype.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sql.Dispose();
```

Comment: Every exception has Message property. You need to check what's the message of the exception. Without that it's not possible to suggest anything

Comment: You have parameters with name `@txtLName` in SQL but you are not adding that parameter in the command. You must use the same parameter names as in query to add to the command.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack overflow. Try to read the exception `Message` as @ChetanRanpariya has recommended and also see if there's an `InnerException` which may give more detail

Comment: An you can not have parameter with `.` in it

Comment: Dan Guzman says: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) - please read the article and stop using it!

Answer (score 0):

A few things with your code...

The parameter names in the query do not match the parameters you are adding with `AddWithValue`, so that's why your query is failing. They need to match, e.g:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO UserRegister(LastName, FirstName, M.I, Username, Password, Email, Address, ContactNumber, Gender, BloodType) VALUES(@txtLName, @txtFName, @txtMI, @txtRegUsername, @txtRegPassword, @txtEmail, @txtHomeAddress, @txtContactno, @cmbGender, @cmbBloodtype)", sql);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtFName", txtFName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtMI", txtMI.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtRegUsername", txtRegusername.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtRegPassword", txtRegpassword.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtEmail", txtEmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtHomeAddress", txtHomeaddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtContactno", txtContactno.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmbGender", cmbGender.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmbBloodtype", cmbBloodtype.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You should also read [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

And rather than call `sql.Dispose();`, instead put your connection object in a [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).